# Completely hide form input value from non-admins without removing form data

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

Having a problem with sensitive data in a client-facing form.

Here's my problem: There is a form where I (as the site admin) can edit certain fields on behalf of a client, but that client shouldn't ever see the data. Here's what I've tried:

1. Disabled input fields and set the field value as "Set by Administrator". Problem: When client saves the form, these fields are wiped (taking the "disabled" fields as being blank).
2. Set input fields as "readonly" and type="password". This saved correctly, but these values are still viewable in the html source code itself (for any clients savvy enough to look there).
3. Removed the input field entirely for non-admins with the text "Set by Administrator". But down the road, the system still tries to save values for these input fields (even if they don't exist), so they still end up coming back blank when I view them as the admin.

Since I'm editing a WordPress plugin, I'd prefer the modifications to be light (in other words, I'd really rather not dig through the code even farther to modify the save content if there is a workable solution here).

Thanks for the help.﻿

Comment: So what should it do? If you don't want the user to ever see the values, (3) seems like your best option, and you can just fill in the blank fields later. A heavier alternative would be to set up some kind of approval procedure for form submissions so that you have a chance to edit them before they're fully submitted.

Comment: You should never, ever send sensitive data to the client. Don't try to hide it somewhere in plain sight, just don't ever send it!

Comment: @Jonathan my thoughts exactly. I don't want to display it to the client at all, and I can easily just not display the data. The problem comes when the form is saved - those values are stored as blank, which overrides my database values (creating a pretty big problem). Again, I'd *rather* not modify the save code, if there is a simpler solution I can implement here.

Comment: @ScottHarris Thanks - that was conclusion I was arriving at as well, I was just hoping there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up editing the downstream save content. I couldn't find a good solution for this in the form itself.